# Geometry Nodes Points Intersecting

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm struggling to find a way to stop vertices from intersecting while using geometry nodes. Trying to do a crowd sim and stop people from colliding but unsure how to go about it. This is what I'm doing so far.

[image: Geometry Node Graph]

This is the issue I'm facing

[image]

I've noticed that using point distribute does the same thing however when using that my point data seems to disappear in the spreadsheet so I'm randomising instead. Not sure if this is the best approach but it's what I've come up with so far.

Also I'm using Blender 3.0 Alpha

Blend File:

https://pasteall.org/blend/f7e0db59a2564ed5940b223c5587f5f2

Comment: You don't fancy using boids to do this?

Comment: I feel like ultimately geometry nodes will give far greater control. Maybe at this stage boids would be quicker but I feel like, maybe I'm wrong, geometry nodes should be far easier when trying to customise a crowd later on in the pipe

Comment: Hmm, don't know why your data seems to disappear in the spreadsheet, but usually I would try it with _Point Distribute_ since the _Poisson Disk_ method has advantage over _Random_, you can set a distance for the distributed points so that the instances don't intersect.

Comment: Oh, can't try your file on my 2.93.1 Blender, seems there is a new node in 3.0 Alpha which is not working.

Comment: I just tried using Poisson disk but it doesn't seem to work in this case because the points are being translated at different speeds so still intersect in on another. I don't know if there is a way for points to detect each other to avoid collision?

Comment: i think the solution you want to have is not solvable by GN right now, because GN cannot loop over all positions and compare them whether there is any kind of intersection. But animation nodes could do this. Maybe you should have a look at this.

Comment: but maybe Gorgious has another of his genius ideas... ;)